# Specific Column Names within a 3d array in R

Tags: arrays, r

I'm trying to name columns within a 3d array in R. But I only want those names to apply to the columns in the 2nd of 3, 3rd dimensions. Here's an example:

```
data <- array(1:72, dim = c(12, 2, 3))
```

The columns I am trying to name are shown below:

```
data[,,2]
      [,1] [,2]
 [1,]   25   37
 [2,]   26   38
 [3,]   27   39
 [4,]   28   40
 [5,]   29   41
 [6,]   30   42
 [7,]   31   43
 [8,]   32   44
 [9,]   33   45
[10,]   34   46
[11,]   35   47
[12,]   36   48
```

I want to name the columns of only [,,2], which for reference corresponds to values 25 through 48 shown above.

I saw this other post (link below), but using dimnames seems to name the columns the same for every dimension. In my question, I need different column names for [,,1] & [,,2] & [,,3].
[3 Dimensional Array Names in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25292739/3-dimensional-array-names-in-r)

Hopefully my question is clear. Thanks in advance!

Comment: In a regular R array this is not allowed -- to have different names at the same dimension. A list of 2D arrays (list(data[,,1], data[,,2], data[,,3])) would work for your case though. Would you consider using a list instead?

Comment: Thanks for the information @I.Brum. I ended up keeping them as matrices and removing one loop.